# Firefox multiple gradient backgrounds bug

Tags: css, firefox, linear-gradients

My goal is to give some divs a top and left inner shadow. To do that, I have given the divs two background-images with `linear-gradient`:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #263B4B  0, transparent 50px),
                  linear-gradient(180deg, #263B4B  0, transparent 50px);
```

This looks fine in Chrome 39 and IE 11, but **not** in Firefox 32. 
Firefox doesn't display it correctly.

At first, I had the following CSS, which worked fine, but since there are many divs with this shadow, the page rendering was extremly slow to unusable, especially on mobile. So I don't want to use `box-shadow`.

```
box-shadow: 18px 31px 95px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) inset;
```

How do I get this to work on Firefox without using an image file?

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/eLkhwoqg/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox's interpolation between other color stops and the `transparent` keyword isn't quite right. Because `transparent` corresponds to `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`, Firefox is using that value to calculate the gradient, except it is doing so in non-premultiplied RGBA space, which results in the gradient transitioning from your given color to black. We know this behavior is in fact incorrect, because the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#color-stop-syntax) says so.

Fortunately, the workaround is easy: simply [use a zero alpha version of the same color you're using](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/eLkhwoqg/5) and Firefox will interpolate the gradient correctly:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, #263B4B  0, rgba(38, 59, 75, 0) 50px),
                  linear-gradient(180deg, #263B4B  0, rgba(38, 59, 75, 0) 50px);
```

Once this is fixed, you will be able to use the `transparent` keyword going forward.